# How to fix RAW query with Squelize

Tags: jquery, sequelize.js, nodes, hapi.js

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT merchant_id as name,count(id) as y FROM table_name WHERE DATE(created_at) = current_date() GROUP BY merchant_id
```

and i will run this query in hapijs with Squelize.

I try like this but is not working, return empty array

```
return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        return await sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then(users => {
            resolve(users)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

what about try this?

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const users = await sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        resolve(users)
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
    });
```

Comment: this case not have error, but my query should be work in sequelize is not working

Comment: i try add `try catch` but nothing

Comment: what is your error clearly? I think you have to provide more informations like your whole promise function and error message. Is `users` array data return well?

Comment: yes in my log not have error, i try to print my query to `console.log` and i run query in mysql terminal it's work, but in my sequelize code is not working